# tracking 301 redirects with awstats

Tags: awstats

I'd like to use awstats to track usage of a URL shortener I'm using.

Unfortunately, awstats treats log records with a non 200 status as an error, and excludes them from statistics.

Is there a way to get awstats to treat 301s as 200s for stats tracking?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. In the configuration file:

`ValidHTTPCodes="200 304 301"`