# nginx: rewrite URL but have original URL stored in access.log as 200

Tags: nginx, http, log-files, awstats

I'm setting up a link tracking system, which (temporarily) involves adding /link/id/ in front of URL (like http://server/data/id/publication/id/).

```
rewrite data/id/(.*) http://server/$1;
```

The request is logged as:

```
ip - - [17/Nov/2011:10:07:19 +0300] "GET /data/id/publication/id.html HTTP/1.1" 302 154 "-" "UA"`
```

For some reason (keeping the compatibility with AWStats) it is wanted to have 200 logged instead of 302. *(nginx allows to get 301 code out of box with permanent option, but thats inappropriate too)*

What are my options here?
Will the combination of `location { }` and `rewrite` do the job?

---

UPDATE: AWstats is able to understand various status codes by setting `ValidHTTPCodes="200 304 301"`, see [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/124271/tracking-301-redirects-with-awstats) question; my problem is solved, but question is still active - any way to get rewrites working without 301/302 code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nginx is doing a client-side redirect because the redirect target has http:// in the URL - you can do a server side redirect (nginx will reread the new URL and send the file directly, with code 200) by just having `rewrite data/id/(.*) /$1;`